# Using tf.custom_gradient in tensorflow r1.8

Tags: tensorflow

#### System information

- **Have I written custom code (as opposed to using a stock example script provided in TensorFlow)**: Y
- **OS Platform and Distribution (e.g., Linux Ubuntu 16.04)**: Ubuntu 16.04
- **TensorFlow installed from (source or binary)**: binary
- **TensorFlow version (use command below)**: r1.8
- **Python version**: 2.7.14
- **GCC/Compiler version (if compiling from source)**: 5.4
- **CUDA/cuDNN version**: 8.0/7.0
- **GPU model and memory**: GTX1080, 8G
- **Bazel version**: N/A
- **Exact command to reproduce**: python test_script.py

#### Describe the problem

Hello, I'm trying to make a custom_gradient op using the function of [tf.custom_gradient](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/custom_gradient). I made my test code based on the API explanation online. However, it seems there is a problem in the custom_gradient function. Thanks!

#### Source code / logs

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

@tf.custom_gradient
def log1pexp(x):
  e = tf.exp(x)
  def grad(dy):
    return dy * (1 - 1 / (1 + e))
  return tf.log(1 + e), grad

x = tf.constant(100.)
f = tf.custom_gradient(log1pexp)

y, dy = f(x)

sess = tf.Session()
print (y.eval(session=sess), y.eval(session=sess).shape)

File "/home/local/home/research/DL/unit_tests/tf_test_custom_grad.py", line 14, in <module>
    y, dy = f(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/custom_gradient.py", line 111, in decorated
    return _graph_mode_decorator(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/custom_gradient.py", line 132, in _graph_mode_decorator
    result, grad_fn = f(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 439, in __iter__
"Tensor objects are not iterable when eager execution is not "
TypeError: Tensor objects are not iterable when eager execution is not enabled. To iterate over this tensor use tf.map_fn.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to test the code in the documentation, here is the way.

The following code will give the instable `[nan]` result:

```
import tensorflow as tf

def log1pexp(x):
    return tf.log(1 + tf.exp(x))

x = tf.constant(100.)
y = log1pexp(x)
dy = tf.gradients(y, x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(dy))
```

And the following code will give the correct result `[1.0]`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

@tf.custom_gradient
def log1pexp(x):
    e = tf.exp(x)
    def grad(dy):
        return dy * (1 - 1 / (1 + e))
    return tf.log(1 + e), grad

x = tf.constant(100.)
y = log1pexp(x)
dy = tf.gradients(y, x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(sess.run(dy))
```

## Details:

The main problem here is that you are trying to decorate `log1pexp` twice in your code: once with `@tf.custom_gradient` and once with `f = tf.custom_gradient(log1pexp)`. In [python](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-decorator), `@tf.custom_gradient` here is equivalent to `log1pexp = tf.custom_gradient(log1pexp)`. You should do this only once, especially here for the following reason.

`tf.custom_gradient` needs to call the function being pass to it to get both the function output and the gradient, i.e. expecting two returns. During decoration, everything works as expected because `log1pexp` returns `tf.log(1 + e)` and `grad`. After decorating `log1pexp`, `log1pexp` (returned by `tf.custom_gradient`) becomes a new function which returns only one tensor `tf.log(1 + e)`. When you do `f = tf.custom_gradient(log1pexp)` after decorating `log1pexp`, `tf.custom_gradient` can only get one return which is the single tensor `tf.log(1 + e)`. It will try to split this tensor into two by iterating this returned tensor. But it is wrong and is not allowed as the error message stated:

> Tensor objects are not iterable when eager execution is not enabled.

You should not decorate `log1pexp` twice anyway. But this is why you got this error. One more thing to mention, your code will trigger another error for the same reason even if you removed `@tf.custom_gradient`. After removing `@tf.custom_gradient`, the line `f = tf.custom_gradient(log1pexp)` should work as expected. But `f` is a function returning only one tensor. `y, dy = f(x)` is wrong and will not work.